# Shell redirection to an integer?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Still learning shell scripting. Can anyone explain this code I have below?

```
obtainAllVersions()
{
        IFS="|"
        while read pkg pkgfiles mac <&9
        do
                rcmd -n $mac hostname 2> /dev/null
        done 9< "$1"
}
```

It's an example modified to just show hostname from a few machines.

What does the `9< "$1"` do? Also, `<&9`.

I know `<` is used for redirection, and `$1` is the first parameter passed to the function. I don't understand why 9, or another number, works, but a letter or letter based string doesn't.

Also, it seems like `9` and `&` (stnd out and stnd err) are being redirected to `read`. Is that right? Does it make sense to do this?

Comment: That's a [file descriptor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), which you can sort of think of as an anonymous file.  [This](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) shows you what else you can do with them in bash.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read the "bash" manual section on "REDIRECTION"
2. The "<&9" syntax causes STDIN to be duped from file descriptor 9
3. The "9< $1" syntax causes file descriptor 9 to be opened from the first argument to the function.

Comment: And the `read` command could use `read -u 9` instead of the redirection (in `bash`).  The reason for doing this is so that the normal standard input is available to the `rcmd` in the body of the loop, and so that the `rcmd` in the body of the loop won't screw up the loop control by reading all the data from the file, etc.